# Testing a recurring cron job with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, cucumber

I want to notify my users at 10AM if one of their Discounts is expiring soon.  I am using heroku's hourly cron. I am on Rails 3.0.9 with Ruby 1.8.7. I have the following cron.rake in lib/tasks/cron:

```
# Notify users with expiring claims
puts "Notifying users with expiring claims..."
if Time.zone.now.hour == 10
  Claim.expiring_tomorrow.reject(&:redeemed?).compact.each do |claim|
    Mailer.delay.notify_customer_claim_expiration(claim)
    claim.update_attribute(:expiration_notified, true)
  end
end
puts "done."
```

That works great. My problem is that I have to test three different Scenarios in cucumber:

```
Scenario: Not receiving a expiration reminder too early
Scenario: Receiving a expiration reminder only once
Scenario: Not receiving a reminder for a redeemed claim
```

and so I wrote the following Feature:

```
Feature: Being reminded that a claimed discount is expiring

  Background:
    Given the hourly cron job exists

  Scenario: Not receiving a expiration reminder too early
    And the hourly cron job has fired

  Scenario: Receiving a expiration reminder only once
    And the hourly cron job has fired

  Scenario: Not receiving a reminder for a redeemed claim
    And the hourly cron job has fired
```

with the following cron.steps Step definition:

```
And /^the hourly cron job exists$/ do
  require "rake"
  @rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = @rake
  Rake.application.rake_require "lib/tasks/cron"
end

And /^the hourly cron job has fired$/ do
  Rake::Task["cron"].invoke
end
```

If I run each Scenario individually, they pass. If I run the whole Feature, it fails on the second (not the first) Scenario with:

```
RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'cron'
```

It seems that the Rake is not persisting past the first Scenario or needs to be reset before the second Scenario runs...?

Thanks...G

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the post. I ended up doing this:

```
And /^a cron job exists$/ do
  require "rake"
  @rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = @rake

  # remove cron.rake from list of required files to force file to be reloaded
  loaded = $".reject {|file| file == Rails.root.join("lib", "tasks", "cron.rake").to_s }

  Rake.application.rake_require("lib/tasks/cron", [Rails.root.to_s], loaded)
  Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
end

And /^the hourly cron job has fired$/ do
  @rake["cron"].invoke
end
```

Comment: You should [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/). It wont increase your reputation, but it will indicate that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rake::Task[].invoke
```

will check if the rake task has already been called, and execute it if not. Ie it will only execute the task once if called multiple times

```
Rake::Task[].execute
```

will just execute the task every time you call it.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I ended upo doing this: